# Запрограммировать формулу с#

Tags: c#

Задача - вычисление скалярного произведения двух одномерных массивов (A и B) с размерностью n по формуле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять как перевести формулу на С# ?

Comment: Ну вы же не понимаете, как реализовать формулу, но как массивы создать я думаю вы знаете. Выложите то что сейчас имеете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поддерживаю @ashes и сначала вам нужно разделить задачу на несколько частей, но подробней напишу об основной части.

Что мы имеем?

1. `S` - итоговая сумма произведений `i`-ых элементов
2. `a` и `b` - массивы
3. `n` - размер этих массивов

Данная формула, если переводить на русский язык, означает: Сумма произведений `i`-тых элементов.

Например:

```
a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
b = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
n = 5
```

Нужно учитывать, то что в формуле `i` начинается с 1, но индексация массивов в `c#` начинается с 0. Значит наш промежуток будет не `[1, n]`, а `[0, n)` или `[0, n - 1]`

Запишу, как высчитывается `S` в одну строчку

```
S = a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2] + a[3]*b[3] + a[4]*b[4]
```

Как мы видим, в каждом слагаемом у нас изменяется только индекс, значит лучше воспользоваться циклом `for` (да да `for` :) )

Сам цикл `for` работает следующим образом:

```
for(int i = начало промежутка; i < конец промежутка; i++)
```

В вашем случае `начало промежутка` = 0, а вот `конец промежутка` = n или если взять промежуток `[0, n - 1]`, то нужно писать `i <= n - 1`.

Ну и осталось за малым, просто написать цикл, который будет проходить промежуток от `[0, n)` и внутри него складывать в переменную `S` изначально равную 0 произведение `i`-тых элементов. (Подсказка: обращение к `i`-му элементу например массива `a` осуществляется так `a[i]`)

Comment: не хватает только примера с компилируемым кодом.

Comment: @aepot я бы мог его написать, но тогда автор все что я написал даже читать не будет.

Comment: так ответ же не только для автора, а для всех пользователей, кто нагуглит ваш пост.

Comment: @aepot я бы вообще закрыл этот вопрос, и если пользователь наткнется на этот пост, то я думаю и ему будет полезно почитать

Comment: @ПавелЕриков если вы так предвзяты к автору, и считаете, что он хочет именно взять готовый код, не вдумываясь, как тот будет работать - зачем вы потратили столько времени на то, чтобы написать ответ?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков т.е. хотите помочь автору - покажите ему нормальный код, и ответьте на поясняющие вопросы (если они будут). Не хотите - пройдите мимо, и не мешайте другим тратить свое время :)

Comment: @PashaPash лично я на любой подобный вопрос отвечаю таким образом. Мне не сложно расписать все, чтобы если автору будет интересно он почитает. А если нет, то он прочитает ваш ответ. Если бы я не хотел помочь, я бы не писал ответ. Зачем писать очевидное "_Не хотите - пройдите мимо_"? Не хочу продолжать с вами этот разговор если честно.

Comment: @PashaPash: Разумеется, затем, чтобы автор вопроса _научился_, а не скопипастил, не понимая сути. Готовый код без объяснения намного хуже объяснения без готового кода.

Comment: @VladD да, понимаю мотивацию. Я не понимаю как можно одновременно пытаться избавить сайт от домашек И пытаться помочь тем, кто тащит сюда домашку. Т.е. если автор хочет разобраться, код с пояснениями лучше, чем пояснения без кода. В конце концов, задаст вопросы, если что-то не поймёт. А если не хочет - то какой смысл ему вообще помогать,  раз он все равно не хочет учиться? :)

Comment: @VladD я про домашки (учебные задания без попыток самостоятельного решения) - потому что этот вопрос именно таким и является. И даже мотивация, озвученная выше - это именно не дать автору вопроса скопипастить код и сдать его, ничему не *научившись*. В прямом смысле, не получить знания от решения учебного задания.

Comment: @PashaPash: да, но я в этой точке не вижу разногласий. Вы понимаете мотивацию ответа, ответ хороший, вроде бы нету потенциала для дискуссии?

Answer (score 2):

Всю задачу можно разделить на части:

1. Инициализация двух динамических массивов размерностью n
2. Заполнение этих массивов
3. Создать переменную answer, которая и будет искомым скалярным произведением
4. Произвести произведение i-тых элементов обоих массивов и к переменной answer прибавить результат этого перемножения, и так далее вплоть до n-ных элементов массивов. Это можно сделать через цикл for

Comment: За что минусовать ответ? Я считаю отличный ответ. Какой условие, такой ответ.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков кто ж в C# сумму массивов for-ом считает....

Comment: @PashaPash агггааа то есть это является причиной голосовать за "Ответ не является полезным"?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков возможно, спросите это у того, кто минусанул )

Comment: @ПавелЕриков думаю, здесь причина в отсутствии поясняющего кода большей частью. P.S. относитесь проще к минусам/плюсам :)

Comment: @АртёмОконечников да не это просто предлог был поддержать ответ. Так я понимаю в принципе за что дали -.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Linq;

var result = a.Zip(b, (ai, bi) => ai * bi).Sum();
```

Zip поэлементно склеивает два массива (как застежка-молния, zip по английски), при этом применяя функцию к каждой паре элементов.

Sum считает сумму.

Comment: Еще вариант `int sum = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => a[i] * b[i]).Sum();`. Разница в том, что для `Zip` нельзя указать `n`.

Comment: @aepot топикастеру и не надо указывать N - у него массивы уже размерность N, т.е. надо просуммировать все элемнты, а не N элементов из какого-то большего числа.

Comment: Воспринимайте мой вариант не "этот лучше", а "еще вот так можно".

Comment: @aepot что значит в тайне? :) "двух одномерных массивов (A и B) с размерностью n" - прямо в тексте вопроса.